# Tails 1.2.2. Strange Login Request at JonDonym ip-test?

Tags: security, tails

First of all: Thanks god for this Forum! I've searched a looong time for something like this! (Had to say...)
Now, THIS!:
I tried to do an IP Request at Jondo's ip-test side (http://ip-check.info/?lang=en). Suddenly a popup message appeared which looks suspicious for me.

```
"A username and password are being requested by http://ipcheck.info. The site says: "This is a test: Please cancel!"
User Name:
Password:
```

"

The popup seems to be system made maybe from "Password and Keys" application. Not "Browser inside". The only way proceeding browsing was to click an option or close the browser.
What's going on there? Is it normal?
I am an absolute Beginner in IT Security related themes. But absolutely charmed about this theme! :-)

Comment: I suspect that it's just testing something related to HTTP authentication; was there no cancel button?

Answer (score 1):

Do not worry, There is no problem. This is the message you get:

```
"A username and password are being requested by http://ipcheck.info. The site says: "This is a test: Please cancel!" User Name: Password: "

User Name:

Password:

                                  OK        Cancel
```

You may `cancel` and continue. There is no need to close the browser and certainly no need to panic. This is normal behavior for this site.

Comment: @Mabuse Dear Mabuse, Thanks for your comment, and you welcome.

Comment: @orf Dear orf, Thanks for your comment, and you welcome. Warm Regards,